# Error During downloading files from S3 to EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

While i am using "wget" command to download files from amazon S3 to amazon EC2 instance,
it gives following message and file not get downloaded.

How to solve this issue..?

**Command** :->

```
"wget https://s3.amazonaws.com/docsbucket/intro.doc"
```

**Error Message** :->

```
"Resolving s3.amazonaws.com... 207.171.163.225
Connecting to s3.amazonaws.com|207.171.163.225|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden
2013-03-20 13:06:00 ERROR 403: Forbidden."
```

Answer (score 2):

You should launch your EC2 instance with the permission to read from your S3 buckets.

The easiest way to do it is using Roles. You simply create in IAM (Identity and access management) service of AWS a role that can read from S3. Then you launch your instance with this role. AWS will take care of getting the right credentials onto the instance and you can get your S3 objects, using S3 CLI tools.

You can use the same "trick" to access other resources and other actions on these resources.

You can read more about it in AWS documentations: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/role-usecase-ec2app.html

Comment: An IAM role will get credentials on to the instance, but you would still need to use a mechanism that used those credentials. The wget command does not use any credentials, and IAM won't add them. The suggestion to use a tool like s3cmd is a good one. That will make use of any role defined.

Answer (score 1):

Unless the file is public, you will need to authenticate with keys to download the file. This is probably easiest done with a tool like `s3cmd`.

Comment: Will you plz tell me how can I do this ?

Answer (score -1):

This worked after I gave read Permission to everyone for the file
Go to Permission Tab - >Public Access->Click Everyone-> then give the Read Permission

Comment: And this is how we end up with S3 buckets with hundreds of thousands of files with personal information open to the Internet. :(